# Python does deepcopy of an object duplicate its static variables?

Tags: python, static, static-variables

I'm used to code in C and Java and I just got into Python.

I have a Class Obj that has 2 static class variables `a` and `b` and has 2 instance variables `x` and `y`. I have an instance of Obj `obj`. During the program I need to make copies of `obj` (i.e. obj2) so that `obj.x` and `obj2.x` are not the same object, but `obj.a` and `obj2.a` are the same object (same pointer).

If I make something like `obj.a = foo`, then `obj2.a == foo` should be true.

I'm creating `obj2` by making `obj2 = copy.deepcopy(obj)`, but they are not sharing the pointer, it's creating another instance `obj2.a` and **using more memory then needed**.

I need them to work exactly like static variables in Java. How can I do this?

Comment: Please update your question with a minimal code snippet which shows what you have so far, the problem that ensues and the expected behaviour.

Comment: Why would you end up on `deepcopy` when you want them to share memory, when it's the exact opposite of what you want?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the basic OOP of Python supports what you want to do. I think you need a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a specific way of working with static fields of classes. If you change the static field of class accessing through an object you will change the value only for this object.

```
obj.a = foo # changes the field a only for obj
```

But if you change field accessing through the class it will change values for all instances of this class.

```
Obj.a = foo # changes the field a for all instances
```

Also if you want to compare references you should use `is` keyword

```
class Dog:
    type="Dog"

a = Dog()
from copy import deepcopy
b = deepcopy(a)
a.type is b.type
>>True
a.type == b.type
>>True
a.type = "Cat"
a.type is b.type
>>False
b.type is Dog.type
>>True
```

Comment: When you call `b = deepcopy(a)`, is there a copy of `type` being created in memory or is the variable `b` just pointing to the same position in the memory as `a`? I don't want to use unnecessary memory.

Comment: will be created new instance but reference to a static field in a and b will be the same